# php file not uploading with error code 0

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files using php to directory that is not in the same directory that the upload script is, here is the structure of dir's:

```
var>www>html>
            foo>index.php //this ones where upload is done
            bar>          //this is where I want to upload it
```

the `index.php` file's `form` element:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="index.php">
            <fieldset style='width:33%;'>
                <legend>UPLOAD PROJECT FILES</legend>
                <select name="dirList" id="dirList" onChange="getSubDir(this.value)" required>
                    <option value="">SELECT PROJECT</option>
                    <?php
                        $path = "../";
                        $scan = scandir($path);
                        foreach($scan as $result){
                            if($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;
                            if(is_dir($path . '/' . $result)){
                                echo "<option value='../$result'>$result</option>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <select name="subDirList" id="subDirList">
                    <option value="">SELECT PATH</option>
                </select>
                <input type="file" name="filePath"/>
                <input type="submit" name = "upload" value="UPLOAD"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

so the idea here is to get the list of folders from first `combobox` which will get me the list of subdirectories in the second `combobox`.

and then the php function at the head of `index.php` for uploading the file:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
            $upload_path = $_POST['subDirList'];
            if($upload_path == ''){
                $upload_path = $_POST['dirList'];
            }
            $upload_path = getcwd().'/'.$upload_path;
            $upload_path = $upload_path.'/'.basename($_FILES['filePath']['name']);              
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filePath"]["tmp_name"], $upload_path)){
                echo "success";
            } else {
                echo print_r($_FILES);
                echo 'fail';
            }

        }
```

the error log:

```
[Wed Sep 23 14:10:46.841250 2015] [:error] [pid 4028] [client 78.167.168.253:52438] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpEB1a3s' to '/var/www/html/eShop/Capture.PNG' in /var/www/html/ftp/index.php on line 16, referer: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/ftp/index.php
```

Comment: Check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @saurabh2836 http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php ;)

Comment: What does the response state? `fail` or `success`? Check the php Log, on the server machine, to be sure that there are no errors there. Also, can you post the `index.php` form as well? Finally, I suggest using `isset($_FILES["submit"]) && $_FILES["submit"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` as well.

Comment: @Bonatti added the rest of code now, it should be bit more clear as to what Im trying to get done

Comment: @mrahmat Before the `if(move_uploaded_file...)` function, echo the `$upload_path` and post in your question. I think you may not have writte permissions there. By default, most servers can only read www and below. `getcwd()`should be outside of that... check the result of `echo __FILE__ `below it as well

Comment: @mrahmat Also [check the folder writte permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723174/php-warning-move-uploaded-file-unable-to-move)

Comment: @Bonatti thx, the problem was with permissions, its working now I used chmod 777 for now for quick solution but I will fix it later with correct permissions, can you write an answer so I can accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check if you have writte permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723174/php-warning-move-uploaded-file-unable-to-move).

[Then, by documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) also check if the file name is valid, and remeber the warning:

`Warning If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.`

As a suggestion, always check that :

`isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)`

is true before continuing.