# Unable to move file in PHP

Tags: php

I randomly started having difficulty moving an uploaded file to another folder. Have checked permissions of videos folder, and have made sure it's writable. I'm using full paths, and haven't had issues with this previously. Any thoughts?

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php5xBeV5' to '/home/main/homes/videos/1440597514_tmp_IMG_20150804_174422551.jpg' in /home/main/public_html/app/classes/video.class.php on line 34

```
 function importVideo() {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $newfilename = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_file =  '/home/main/homes/videos/'.$filename;
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_file);

}
```

Comment: The error doesn't originate from that code - your $newfilename is 7 hex chars, but the error message has a more complex name.

Comment: The error provided was with $filename being used, I must have copied old code.  Updated now.

Comment: Check if this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13723279/4611395) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I've already tried that and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Might not be related but I've noticed you don't use `$ext` anywhere.

Comment: Unrelated, I simplified and removed a lot of the code for easy reading. But current snippet is still providing this error.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was logged into a cloned server and the directories I was referencing didn't actually exist on the server I was referencing. Thanks for attempted help.