# Trying to upload images to a small page (I am absolute beginner)

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am an absolute beginner, and this code is actually much too difficult for me, but I would love the result, so I keep trying ...

**Goal**: let users add images to my folder called /public_html/uploads/ from this small page https://stegemueller.dk/upload-image/index.php (I first try to make it work, and then comes the design later on):

**Actual results**: None ... but the url responds that the upload was successful: "https://stegemueller.dk/upload-image/index.php?uploadsuccess" This header can be found in line 22.

**Error messages**: The folder is not being populated and the error log says for example this:

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/public_html/uploads/ 6322e3df84ff59.44735736 . test.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stegemue/public_html/upload-image/upload.php on line 21

**I have tried this**: Normally my images are called e.g. "Andersen, Hanne.jpg". I thought the issue might be the comma in the filename. I tried to rename an image and called it test.jpg. As you can see from the error message, that did not help.

I guess the problem is the white-spaces in the filename that PHP tries to place in the folder, but I don't know how to get rid of them.

**My starting point** was this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaRq73y5MJk and I have only added ( and destroyed :-) ) line 13, saying:
$imgtype = substr($fileActualExt, strpos($fileActualExt, ".") + 1);

I hope someone can explain to me which silly errors I make.

**My code is here**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$fileName =  $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileTmpName =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$fileSize =  $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$fileError =  $_FILES["file"]["error"];
$fileType =  $_FILES["file"]["type"];

$fileExt = explode(',',  $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$imgtype = substr($fileActualExt, strpos($fileActualExt, ".") + 1);
$allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf", "tmp");

if (in_array ($imgtype, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid( ' ', true) . " . " .$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = "/public_html/uploads/".$fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
        } else {
            echo "Your file is too big! Din fil er for stor!";
        }

    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file! Der skete en fejl, da du prøvede at uploade filen!";
    }
} else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type. Denne type filer kan ikke uploades!";
    }
}
```

Is it normal, that **I do not get notified** when there is an answer to my question? I do want to be polite and answer/comment as fast as possible.

Hi mhaendler Thank for your reply!

I try to mark my code but I can't make it work. I mark all lines, then press CTRL K, but that is not accepted.

I now get this:

https://stegemueller.dk/upload-image/index.php?uploadsuccess

PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpf60x1G' to '/public_html/uploads/63232299eadf46.77449704 . test.jpg' in /home/stegemue/public_html/upload-image/upload.php on line 21

```
code looks like this: 

I must do something silly wrong with those white spaces, but I can't see them:

if (in_array ($imgtype, $allowed)) { if ($fileError === 0) { if ($fileSize < 1000000) { $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true) . " . ". $fileActualExt; $fileDestination = "/public_html/uploads/".$fileNameNew; move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination); header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the issue might be the comma in the filename

Close i see a few error's here.

```
$fileNameNew = uniqid( ' ', true) . " . " .$fileActualExt;
```

You generate a new filename with quite a few whitespaces. Remove the whitespaces from your filename :). It's just quick guess, but i think that where you get the error from.

> PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(/public_html/uploads/ 6322e3df84ff59.44735736 . test.jpg):

the error shows that your filename contains multiple whitespaces.

In the video you watched, "uniqid" is without an whitespace in it.

```
uniqid('', true)
```

//EDIT
Sorry made a silly typo in uniqid

Comment: Oh of course, I should have seen the extra white space. 

I have removed it now. So I have this code: 
"$fileNameNew = uniquid('', true) . " . " .$fileActualExt;"

That makes two things happen:

1) The header (index.php?uploadsuccess) does not show up any more.

2) The file is not uploaded - and the errorlog now returns:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function uniquid() in /home/stegemue/public_html/upload-image/upload.php:19


I have also adjusted the permissions on the folder called /public_html/uploads to "777"

Best regards,

Comment: Let's examine the next error:

>Error: Call to undefined function uniquid() in

Sorry i made a typo in my previous post, after fixing that.. how are things going now?

Comment: I make an answer because this site keeps telling me my comment is to long. Sorry for the delay. Hanne

Answer (score 0):

Try for the first time
Change `uniqid(' ', true)` to `uniqid('', true)`.

If it is still not resolved, you can check the directory permission settings of the file to be created and whether there are relevant permissions.

Comment: Thank you!

I have 
1) removed the white space
2) Adjusted permissions for the folder: "/public_html/uploads" to 777.

Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Beste regards.

Comment: @Stegemüller About `PHP Warning: move_ uploaded_ File () disable to move` error. I wonder if it can be solved: [PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file() unable to move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723174/php-warning-move-uploaded-file-unable-to-move)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study that solution as well. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The **solution** is here:

My friend wrote this:

> I had to change the code a bit. Think maybe it wanted a relative path
> instead of a fixed path. That is, the path to the upload directory is
> defined with ../uploads/. The two dots mean that you go one folder
> back from where the file is located. In this case, it corresponds to
> going back to public_html.

Originally I had:

```
$fileDestination = "/public_html/uploads/".$fileNameNew;
```

It should be this instead:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

This means that lines 16 - 34 should look like this:

```
if (in_array ($imgtype, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $uploads_dir = '../uploads';
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
                header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
            } else {
                echo "Din fil er for stor!";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Der skete en fejl, da du prøvede at uploade filen! Prøv evt. igen";
        }
    } else {
            echo "Denne type filer må ikke uploades!";
        }
}
```